# Rails request statistics gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, statistics

I'm looking for a rails plugin to show request statistics (# of sql queries, time, etc) on each request while in development mode. Something like http://getglimpse.com/ would be great. I've seen one or two of these before but for the life of me I can't find them. Any help?

Ideally, it would show in the header or the footer of every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few including the one I was thinking about and some others.

This one is amazing so far:

[https://github.com/dsboulder/query_reviewer](https://github.com/nesquena/query_reviewer)

This is the one I was thinking of:

https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes

This seems to be a similar but better plugin to rails-footnotes:

https://github.com/brynary/rack-bug

May be best to mix and match these, try rack-bug and query_reviewer

A few others are linked from [query_reviewer](https://github.com/nesquena/query_reviewer)

Comment: Seems the query reviewr hath moved to:

https://github.com/nesquena/query_reviewer